# Combining two rasters into heatmap using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, heat-map, combine

How to combine two rasters so that the heatmap is following according to the relief or shade layer (so that it does not look patched)?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Please provide an example of what you are looking for.